# What tool can I use to to rip DVD movies?

Tags: dvd, video-conversion, ripping, video-encoding

What tool can I use to to rip DVD movies? I have used "Dr. DivX" long back. Is there any better tool to rip DVDs?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[**Handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr/)

> HandBrake is an open-source,
>   GPL-licensed, multiplatform,
>   multithreaded video transcoder,
>   available for MacOS X, Linux and
>   Windows.

**Input:**

- Any DVD-like source: VIDEO_TS folder, DVD image or real DVD (unencrypted--protection methods including CSS are not supported internally and must be handled externally with third-party software and libraries), and some .VOB and .TS files
- Most any multimedia file it can get libavformat to read and libavcodec to decode.

**Output:**

- File format: MP4, MKV, <del>--AVI--</del> or OGM
- Video: MPEG-4, H.264, or Theora (1 or 2 passes or constant quantizer/rate encoding)
- Audio: AAC, MP3, Vorbis or AC-3 pass-through (supports encoding of several audio tracks)

Screenshot:

[image]

Here are some good tutorials:

- [Tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBAhQqLZ6E8)
- [Rip DVD's for Your iPod, Apple TV or iPhone](http://www.methodshop.com/gadgets/tutorials/handbrake/index.shtml)
- [How to Rip DVDs with Handbrake](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/109)

Comment: Yes <3 There's also HandbrakeCLI, a command line version, which is easily scriptable

Comment: Handbrake is amazing.

Comment: handbrake 0.94 no longer supports the avi container

Comment: Alternatively, you can use MediaCoder, which lets you output to nearly any format you can think of.  However, it's not as user-friendly as HandBrake.  It's picky, and has real pain-in-the-donkey ads (thankfully only when you are using the config wizard)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how many features you need, and how proficient you are in doing things.

Personally I prefer simple, so I always use [Fair Use Wizard](http://www.fairusewizard.com/lang_en/fairuse_wizard_dvd_divx_xvid_backup_tool_light_edition.html) (freeware).

Comment: I like FairUse Wizards feature-set, but it keeps crashing for me (on two separate computers). HAndbrake had no such issues.

Comment: I occasionally have discs that give me some problems in FairUse, but by no means many... I have found that problem discs usually behave when I clean them, or when I use AnyDVD at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I use [DVDDecrypter](http://www.mrbass.org/dvdrip/) to rip, and [AutoGK](http://www.autogk.me.uk/) to do the actual encoding. It's a two-step process, but I haven't found a simple encoder that supports removing CSS, so you'll always have to rip encrypted DVD's. AutoGK is a single screen app where you set the source and the output, sound options and optionally subtitle options, then you add the job to a queue. Start the queue and out pops your DivX or XVid AVI file a little bit later.

http://www.videohelp.com/ has a ton of great information regarding computer video and encoding.

Answer (score 2):

[VidCoder](http://vidcoder.codeplex.com/) is a new UI for HandBrake in Windows. It calls into the HandBrake libraries directly rather than wrapping the command line interface, so it's a bit cleaner and has more features.

- No command windows popping up every time an encode starts
- Instant static previews of the video you're encoding
- Pause and resume the encode

The whole interface and preset system has been overhauled and streamlined as well.

Full disclosure: I wrote it. But it's still awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the combination of DVDDecryptor and AutoGK does not do ripping tv shows very well when the episodes are actually chapters. Have to resort to using yet another tool to do chapter splitting. I blogged about it in more detail:

http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/?p=43

PS +million for Handbrake. Just encoded an iPhone video - super fast, good file size and good quality.

Answer (score 0):

I use SlySoft CloneDVD Mobile. Commercial, but it works every time, and you don't need to read a tutorial.

This has profiles for almost any device (iPhone, BlackBerry, AppleTV H264, Zune, Nokia, Sony Ericson, PSP, PlayStation), but you can also create standard DivX i the resolution you like.

It sopports 3 passes (takes a long time!). And it is easy to select subtitle, audio. Zoom, Quality/Size etc.

A realy nice product.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypting with [RipIt4me](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/RipIt4Me) or [DVDFab HD Decrypter](http://www.dvdfab.com/free.htm) (Remove protections that DVD Decrypter doesn't)

And encoding with [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/)

[image]

Not the easiest one but easy enough and powerful.