# How to convert DVD movies to MP4?

Tags: dvd, video-conversion, mp4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best tool to convert DVD films to avi (ripping)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12778/which-is-the-best-tool-to-convert-dvd-films-to-avi-ripping)

How do I convert movies from the format on DVDs to MP4?

Comment: Programmaticaly? or are you just looking for software?

Answer (score 12):

[**handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr/)

Comment: You beat my to the punch! But I agree with thomasrutter; HandBrake is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Handbrake will post a problem on Windows and Linux, Windows because it's a lot stricter DRM-wise, and Linux because it doesn't have a Linux version anymore :'-(. On Windows, HowToGeek has a very nice guide for that: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13516/convert-dvd-to-mp4-h.264-with-hd-decrypter-and-handbrake/

Comment: DRM is problematic, but tools like DVDFab Decrypter and AnyDVD and DVD43 it's bit too difficult to rip the dvds.

Answer (score 0):

**[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/)** is your friend.

> MediaCoder is a free universal media
>   transcoder since 2005. It integrates
>   most popular audio/video codecs and
>   tools in an elegant and transparent
>   manner into an all-in-one transcoding
>   solution.

Answer (score 0):

My method is to use DVDDecrypter in "Single FILE mode" (no splitting) to aggregate the .VOB data into a single .VOB on my hard drive and then use **[AVIDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)** to rip the video as a .AVI container with .mp3 audio and MPEG-4 video.  Easy.  Usually a 20 minute process.