# What's the easiest way to rip a DVD on Windows and have the files compressed?

Tags: dvd, ripping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DVD ripper for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/4387/dvd-ripper-for-windows)
>   [Which is the best tool to convert DVD films to avi (ripping)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12778/which-is-the-best-tool-to-convert-dvd-films-to-avi-ripping)

I tried DVD Shrink, but it doesn't compress while ripping. I need an easy way to rip a DVD straight to a compressed format. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy answer since most DVD/blue-rays are copyrighted but if your willing to go the legit route get http://www.dvdfab.com/ by far is amazing and worth the money, I also have some opensource ones but they are more complicated  to use.

Comment: this solved my problem. well worth the 50 bucks.

Comment: Ahh, good to know this got the job done. Is the final video quality good?

Answer (score 3):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) will do that I believe.  I've only used it for DVD's I had pre-ripped, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Doesnt accept copy-righted dvds...

Comment: Doing so would be in violation of the DMCA as breaking the encryption even for fair-use reasons is considered illegal (in the US anyhow). It was probably left out intentionally so the US Gov wouldn't bully the author.

Comment: Illegal to copu your own dvds?! *sigh* Dumb law.